# Editing value on xml with xpath causes nullpointerexception in java

Tags: java, xml, xpath

We are attempting to edit number, dateFrom and dateTo on the following xml file using Java:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urn:receive
        xmlns:urn="urn:xxx"
        xmlns:ns="xxx"
        xmlns:ns1="xxx"
        xmlns:urn1="urn:xxx">
    <ns:info>
        <ns:TransaktionIdentifikator>xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx</ns:TransaktionIdentifikator>
        <ns:TransaktionTid>2015-11-22T12:00:00.146+02:00</ns:TransaktionTid>
    </ns:info>
    <urn:give>
        <urn:giveNumber>
           <ns1:number>12345678</ns1:number>
        </urn:giveNumber>
        <urn:giveDates>
            <urn1:dateFrom>2021-07-01</urn1:dateFrom>
            <urn1:dateTo>2021-09-30</urn1:dateTo>
        </urn:giveDates>
    </urn:give>
</urn:receive>
```

We are using xpath to parse the xml file and then transformer to update the xml file with the following lines of code:

```
public class test {

    public void receiveFunc() {
        String serviceResponse = "";
        String tests = "12344321";
        try {

            // our XML file for this example
            File xmlFile = new File("{name}.xml");

            DocumentBuilderFactory f = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder b = f.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = b.parse(xmlFile);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

            Node SENummer = (Node) xPath                
               .compile("/urn:receive/urn:give/urn:giveNumber/ns1:number")
               .evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);

            SENummer.setTextContent(tests);

            Transformer tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
            tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
            tf.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");

            DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(doc);
            StreamResult sr = new StreamResult(new File("{name}.xml"));
            tf.transform(domSource, sr);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Do notice that in the example above, that number should be updated with the string test with the value '12344321', but this does not occur and we receive a nullpointer exception. We believe that the exception is caused because of this line:

```
Node SENummer = (Node) xPath
     .compile("/urn:receive/urn:give/urn:giveNumber/ns1:number")
     .evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

Perhaps it is not correctly addressed. dateTo and dateFrom should be 'easy' to update after we have found out what causes the nullpointer exception.

**Stacktrace:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at dk.skat.rsu.b2b.sample.test.receiveFunc(test.java:173)
    at dk.skat.rsu.b2b.sample.mvc.ServiceTestAction.execute(ServiceTestAction.java:62)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.ExecuteAction.execute(ExecuteAction.java:58)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractExecuteAction.execute(AbstractExecuteAction.java:67)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:305)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:852)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1650)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:530)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:256)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:708)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:626)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)## Heading ##
```

Comment: Use a namespace aware DocumentBuilderFactory and use a namespace resolver for the XPath that resolves the prefixes `urn` and `ns1` you use to the relevant namespaces from the XML document.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Do you provide an example / solution of how to do that? I have initialized a namespace aware with 'f.setNamespaceAware(true);', but not sure how to use a namespace resolver for the XPath that resolve the prefixes

Comment: Use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html#setNamespaceContext-javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext- on the XPath object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest code, given your XML, would be to exploit the lookup methods of the DOM document to initiate a namespace context on the fly:

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    documentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);

    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

    Document document = documentBuilder.parse("sample1.xml");

    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

    xpath.setNamespaceContext(new NamespaceContext() {
        @Override
        public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
            return document.lookupNamespaceURI(prefix);
        }

        @Override
        public String getPrefix(String namespaceURI) {
            return document.lookupPrefix(namespaceURI);
        }

        @Override
        public Iterator getPrefixes(String namespaceURI) {
            return null;
        }
    });


    Node SENummer = (Node)xpath.evaluate("/urn:receive/urn:give/urn:giveNumber/ns1:number", document, XPathConstants.NODE);
```